# React Native AWS Amplify PubSub error: "AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined"

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, aws-iot

I am using AWS Amplify to connect to AWS IoT Core and getting error "AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined." I have integrated aws amplify in expo app.

**Error details**

errorCode: 7
errorMessage: "AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined."
invocationContext: undefined

**Code**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Amplify, { PubSub, Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { AWSIoTProvider } from "@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib/Providers";

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: "ap-south-1:xx-xx-xx-xx-xx",
    region: "AP_SOUTH_1",
    userPoolId: "ap-south-1_xx",
    userPoolWebClientId: "xxx"
  }
});
Amplify.addPluggable(
  new AWSIoTProvider({
    aws_pubsub_region: "ap-south-1",
    aws_pubsub_endpoint: "wss://xx.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mqtt"
  })
);
class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    Auth.configure();
    const sub1 = PubSub.subscribe("$aws/things/xxx/shadow/update").subscribe({
      next: data => console.log("Message received", data),
      error: error => console.error(error),
      close: () => console.log("Done")
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need an answer but I found what eventually solved it for me was going to the IAM console and finding the role which looks like this: `arn:aws:iam::<accountID>:role/<amplify-project-identifier>-authRole`

I then added the `IoTDataAccess` policy to the role and then retried the publish and subscription and it seemed to work.